# Java jdbc warning when using TYPE_SCROLL_ SENSITIVE

Tags: java, jdbc

This is quoted from **OCA/OCP Java® SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide (Exams 1Z0-803 & 1Z0-804)** book :

> For example, suppose that we mistakenly set the result set type to
>   TYPE_SCROLL_ SENSITIVE when creating a Statement object. This does not
>   create an exception; instead, the database will handle the situation
>   by chaining a SQLWarning to the Connection object and resetting the
>   type to TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY (the default) and continue on.

I don't know why setting the statement of type TYPE_SCROLL_ SENSITIVE will cause resetting the type to TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, am I missing anything?

As per above this code will setting the type back to TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

```
Connection conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/BookSellerDB",
"bookguy", "$3lleR");
Statement stmt =
conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
String query = "SELECT * from Book WHERE Book.Format = 'Hardcover'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/resltse2.htm#1018253

> To produce a scroll-sensitive result set:
>
> - A query cannot use "`SELECT *`". (But see the workaround below.)
> - A query can select from only a single table.
> - A query cannot use `ORDER BY`.

It continues:

> If the specified result set type or concurrency type is not feasible, the Oracle JDBC driver uses the following rules in choosing alternate types:
>
> - If the specified result set type is `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, but the JDBC driver cannot fulfill that request, then the driver attempts a downgrade to `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`.
> - If the specified (or downgraded) result set type is `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, but the JDBC driver cannot fulfill that request, then the driver attempts a downgrade to `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

Ok, those are Oracle Database specific, but it shows an example of downgrading.